# WebApi controller - How to hide some fields of a class in dbcontext result?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, dbcontext

I have a class that has another class inside, but this class has some fields that i don´t want to show when call this controller.
So, how can i hide ?

I tried to Include and do a Select with a new Class DTO, but not success.
For example:

```
public class Father
{
 public string name {get;set}
 public FamilyName familyName {get;set;}
}
public class FamilyName
{
 public string name {get;set}
 public string sex {get;set}
}

Controller 

public IQueryable<Father> GetFathers()
{
 return db.Fater;
}
```

When i call the context Father, i have a Json with name and sex. If i need to just show the field "name", how should I do ?

Comment: In the GetFathers() method, you need to fetch all the Father objects from the database and explicitly map them to the Father DTO object.

Comment: Create another DTO class with fields you want to show in controller and map its values from entity class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> You are Exposing database entities to the client, The client
>   receives data that maps directly to your database tables, that's not
>   always a good idea

You can define a data transfer object (DTO). A DTO is an object that defines how the data will be sent over the network.

**DTO Class**

```
public class FatherDTO
{
   public string name { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public IQueryable<FatherDTO> GetFathers()
{
   return new FatherDTO(){ name = db.Fater.name };
}
```

You can convert to DTOs manually in code. Another option is to use a library like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) that handles the conversion automatically.

For more details check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-5)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to do so.

1.Create an anon. type with the wanted properties.

```
// controller
public object GetFathers()
{
    return db.Father.Select(f => new 
    { 
       name = f.name, 
       familyName = new { name = f.familyName.name }
    });
}
```

2.Create a DTO or the same class with a new instance using select. In order to do that, you will need the query to execute since EF cannot translate `new Father` into sql.

```
// controller
public IEnumerable<Father> GetFathers()
{
    return db.Father.ToList().Select(f => new Father
    { 
       name = f.name, 
       familyName = new FamilyName { name = f.familyName.name }
    });
}
```

3. Do stuff with the JSON serializer (custom attributes\custom converters etc.)